# avoid repeating of result using JavaScript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi guys I have been wondering how can I avoid displaying of the same result on JavaScript or jQuery using for loop

Here is my code:

```
function displayData(e)
{
var html = '';
var html2 = '';
var x = '';

var mapDiv = document.getElementById('mapContainer'), i = 0,
     dataIndex, tooltipDiv, key
mapMarkers = $(mapDiv).find('.e-mapMarker'), index = 0;
var divCont = $(mapDiv).find('#rightdiv'), index = 0;
for (i = 0; i < mapMarkers.length; i++)
{

    if (e.target.parentNode.parentNode == mapMarkers[i])
    {
        index = i;

    }
}

html += '<div id="infocontainer">';
html += '<div class="p-image"><img src="src/images/retrofit.png"/></div>';
html += '<div class="popupdetail">';
html += '<div class="p-name"> Site Name: ' + flsSites[index].site_name + '</div>';
html += '<div class="p-name"> Site Status: ' + flsSites[index].status + '</div>';
html += '<div class="p-name"> Country: ' + flsSites[index].country_name + '</div>';
html += '</div>';
html += '</div>';




html2 += '<div class="rightcontainer">';
html2 += '<img id="productimage" src="src/images/retrofit.png" onclick="DisplayProfileCard();"/>';
html2 += '<div id="imagedetail">';
html2 + '<input type="hidden" value='+ flsSites[index].serial_number +'/>';
html2 += '<span class="details">Product Type:' + flsSites[index].serial_number +'</span>';
html2 += '<span class="details">Version / Size <img class="row_one_icon lightbulb_icon" id="lightbulb" src="src/images/lightbulb1.png" onClick="LightBulb()" /><img id="convert" class="row_one_icon arrow_icon" src="src/images/arrow_Off.png" onClick="Conversion()"/><img id="lightning" class="row_one_icon" src="src/images/lightningOff.png" onClick="Lightning()"/><img id="bullseye" class="row_one_icon bullseye" src="src/images/bullseye_off.png" onClick="BullsEye()"/></span>';
html2 += '<span class="details">Estimated annual Spend <img class="row_one_icon ribbon" src="src/images/ribbon1.png"/><img class="row_one_icon map" src="src/images/map1.png"/><img class="row_one_icon paper_stack" id="paper" src="src/images/paper_stack_Off.png" onclick="PaperStack()"/><img class="row_one_icon chain" id="chain" src="src/images/chain_Off.png" onClick="ChainLink()"/></span>';
html2 += '<span class="details">Site name / manufacturer</span>';
html2 += '<span class="details">Selling Sales Eng</span>';
html2 += '</div>'
html2 += '</div>';

if (!document.getElementById('map_tooltip')) 
{
    tooltipdiv = $("<div></div>").attr('id', "map_tooltip");
    $(document.body).append(tooltipdiv);
    $(tooltipdiv).css({
        "display": "none", "padding": "5px",
        "position": "absolute",
        "z-index": "13000",
        "cursor": "default",
        "font-family": "Segoe UI",
        "color": "#707070",
        "font-size": "12px", "pointer-events": "none",
        "background-color": "#FFFFFF",
        "border": "1px solid #707070"
    });
}
else
{

    tooltipdiv = $("#map_tooltip");
    $(tooltipdiv).css({
        "left": (e.pageX + 5),
        "top": (e.pageY + 5)
    });
    $(tooltipdiv).html(html).show("slow");
    //$('#defaulttext').hide();
    //$('#searchcontainer').append(html2);
    //$('.rightcontainer').eq($(this).index()).addClass('background');
    $(html2).appendTo("#searchcontainer");
}
```

Now in this code I was able to display my result on a div by hovering on a marker on the map but if I return on my previous hovered marker instead of highlighting its corresponding result, it will just make another rendering of the same result below in which I dont need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [Set object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) to store each result you renderer and check if it is already there before to render each one.

Unfortunately that *Set objects* aren't supported in older browsers.

But you can emulate it by simply using the keys of a regular object. For example:

```
var Idx = {};
function renderOne(flsSite) {
    if (Idx[flsSite.name]) return; // Here I suppose same name => same result.
    Idx[flsSite.name] = true; // Mark as rendered.
    // Do render...
};
```

Hope it helps...